# Cambiar el nombre del archivo

Tags: java, jfilechooser

alguno sabe como cambiar el texto inicial en el espacio en blanco a la par de  "Nombre de archivo" del JFileChooser de java[image: JFileChooser]?

Answer (score 0):

Para ello basta con especificarle un archivo mediante el método `setSelectedFile`:

```
JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
jFileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File(miRuta + "myFile.txt"));
jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
```

Es importante notar que el archivo ni siquiera necesita existir.